# Admin Panel Slowdown After SSL Verification

Tags: htaccess, iis

a few days ago I did SSL verification for my website. I've imported the following rules on IIS after receiving the http 500 error frequently today.

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{URL}" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
```

Obviously I have no idea much about this rule. I'm binding on IIS 8.5 and I use letsencrypt for SSL.

The HTTP 500 problem seems to have been solved for now. But there is a serious slowness especially in the admin panel.

Website URL is: aryadavetiye.com

IIS Version: 8.5

PHP Version: 7.0.21

So how can troubleshooting for this problem? And of course, how can I fix the problem?